# Definite Integrals of Functions.

Tags: complex-numbers

> With the aid of the  result below evaluate the integral

$$\int_{C}z^m {\bar z^n}dz$$

> where $m$ and $n$ are integers and $C$ is the unit circle $\left | z \right |=1$, taken counterclockwise.

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{im\theta}e^{-in\theta}d\theta=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 ....m\neq n\\ 
2\pi... m=n
\end{matrix}\right.$$

> for $m=n$

$$I=2\pi$$

> for $m\neq n$

$$I=-\frac{i}{m-n}e^{i2\pi(m-n)}+\frac{i}{m-n}e^0$$
$$e^{i2\pi(m-n)}=1$$$$I=0$$

> Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : You have $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$, so $z^m=|z|^me^{im\theta}$ and ${\bar z^n}=|z|^ne^{-in\theta}$.